# Do categorical columns in parquet files slow down AWS Athena queries?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a set of parquet files that I clean with pandas, put in s3, and then query with Athena. I want to make some of the columns have a categorical data type. I believe Athena does not have a categorical data type in their schema so I have it set to string for those columns. Does this have any negative affects on Athena performance?

Comment: String is fine. Parquet uses dictionary and run encoding, which is very effective for low cardinality categorical variables. This is a good video on parquet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j8SdS7s_NY . It's from Databricks, but only briefly touches on tool specific features. Then there is a whole mess of file properties you can fine tune if needed.